# Displaying NSMutableArray in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've made a `UITableView` in my `ViewController`. In this table view I want to add my data from `NSMutableArray`, but it does not seem to add the data. Any ideas?

This is the code I'm using.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    scoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *myVehicle = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Escape", @"name", @"SUV", @"type", nil];
    [scoreArray addObject:myVehicle];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [[scoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[scoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"type"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did u set delegate and datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code you should be able to see one row. But here with no details, the problem is quite difficult to be identified.

Anyway, verify the following:

- Does the datasource (and delegate) is set? This is done via XIB or by code?
- Did you implement `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` correctly?

Sample

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [scoreArray count];
}
```

The method `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` should be implemented if you need a number of sections greater than 1. By default returns one.

In addition, I would modify a little bit the `viewDidLoad` method like the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // call it before any further initialization

    scoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *myVehicle = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Escape", @"name", @"SUV", @"type", nil];
    [scoreArray addObject:myVehicle];
}
```

Comment: 1: by code
2: no have not implement - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger).

Comment: i've done exactly like this, but nothing shows in the UIViewTable. Justto be sure, the viewtable should be dynamic property right?

Comment: No. Remove the `@dynamic`. Just use `@property` in the interface (or wherever you want) and remember to link the correct table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .h file indicates that this is the delegate for the UITableView:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Also make sure you implement the required datasource methods. In addition to what you have, you must have these:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [scoreArray count];
}
```

Comment: i've done exactly like this, but nothing shows in the UIViewTable.